# In R: Type conversion of data frames with mixed data types

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I generally like R, but the type conversion issues are driving me crazy.

Following issue:

I read a data frame from a database connection. The result is a data frame with character columns.

I know that the first column is a date format - all the others are numeric. However, no matter how I tried to convert the character columns of the data frame into the correct types, it didn't work out.

Upon conversion of the data frame into a matrix and then back into a data frame, all columns became type factor - and casting factors into numerics created wrong results cause the indices of the factor levels were converted instead of the real values.

Moreover, if the table is big in size - I do not want to convert each column manually. Isn't there a way to get this done automatically?

Comment: if you read the table via `read.table` you can specify the argument `colClasses` which should be a vector of classes to be assumed for the columns. See `?read.table` for more info.

Comment: This may help in that situation. But it wouldn't be handy for converting a bunge of columns automatically. It is kind of a manual procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `type.convert` by looping over the columns of the dataset with `lapply`.  Convert the columns to `character` and apply the `type.convert`.  If it is is a `character` class, it will convert to `factor` which we can reconvert it to `Date` class (as there is only a single column with `character` class.  It is not sure about the format of the 'Date' class, so in case it is a different format, specify the `format` argument in `as.Date`).

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) {x1 <- type.convert(as.character(x))
                         if(is.factor(x1))
                             as.Date(x1) else x1})
```

Comment: Thanks! This procedure actually solves the problem. But I wonder if such an effort (defining your own function and converting back and forths between character and other types) is really needed in R.

Comment: @user1881788  You may use the `read_csv` from `library(readr)` which should automatically pick up the column class.